# Authentication and Session with Capacitor JS

Tags: node.js, express, cross-platform, capacitor

I'm trying to make a cross platform website/app and I want to implement a remember me/keep me logged in feature.

My stack is React, Node/Express, Postgres, Capacitor

I've been looking at a lot of code, libraries, articles, and I can't seem to figure out a good way to handle user auth, session when using a cross platform framework like capacitor js.

Oauth tokens, JWT, etc I've looked at for a while, but I'm not quite sure how to use them since all the security things I look at say not to persist jwt for too long since it can be stolen?

What's the proper way to handle session verification upon return? Do you have the token expire after a certain number of months? This is all stuff I want to do correctly since I'm deathly afraid of making something in the future with a security flaw.

Comment: Have you considered using a authentication system such as Auth0 or Firebase Authentication?

Comment: I had considered firebase (since I've used it before), but it doesn't have a full implementation in capacitor, so I wasn't sure if I wanted to use it. I have to implement things for custom auth tokens anyway so I figured I might as well do the whole thing.

Comment: Okay I understand. Can I still ask what you were missing from Firebase Authentication? I am the maintainer of `@capacitor-firebase` and would like to know what is holding you back.

Comment: No problem, Auth0 doesn't work for my custom token needs since I need too many on the low tier plan. That library looks great, it didn't come up in any of my searches, so I thought I would have to figure out a different solution. Thanks for sharing it, I'll definitely make use of it.

Comment: Great to hear that! Reach out if you have any questions!